# Android Camera : Picture should not be stored locally but should be saved temporarily in the App

Tags: android, storage, android-camera, android-service

I am new to android and am trying to make an android app where the user can click an image and  save it to a database . However i do not want the image to be stored locally in the gallery folder. Or everytime a picture is taken it saves itself in a self made directory on the phone and keeps replacing earlier pics .I donot want all pictures to be stored on the phone .

Below is my current code :

```
package com.example.camerastart;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CameraMainActivity extends Activity 
{

    private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 2500;
    private Button cam_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_main);

        cam_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        cam_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
              Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
              ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
              imageview.setImageBitmap(image);
        }
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_camera_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can make a folder, and save all the images to this folder.
just remember to add .nomedia file to this folder, and then the gallery will not show those files